# Error converting data type varchar to numeric for SAPbobsCOM.Recordset insert statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016, sapb1

I have a program that runs fine in SQL 2019 but throws an error when I try to run it in another environment in SQL 2016.

The column where the error is thrown is the amount column.

[image]

When the amount column value has a decimal point, this throws an error in the SQL 2016 environment: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric`.

Changing from double to decimal does not help. Removing the single quotes brings another error: `There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause`

What do I need to do to fix this?

Code:

```
if (rsCD.RecordCount > 0)
{
    docNum = rsCD.Fields.Item("DocNum").Value;
    subFileNo = rsCD.Fields.Item("Project").Value;
    containerSize = rsCD.Fields.Item("U_DCC_CNTS").Value;
    hawb = rsCD.Fields.Item("NumAtCard").Value;
    serviceMode = "Clearing";
    weight = (double)rsCD.Fields.Item("Quantity").Value;
    noOfPackages = Convert.ToInt32(rsCD.Fields.Item("FreeTxt").Value);
    cardCode = rsCD.Fields.Item("CardCode").Value;
    cardName = rsCD.Fields.Item("CardName").Value;
    amount = (double)rsCD.Fields.Item("DocTotalFC").Value;                               
    contactNo = rsCD.Fields.Item("Phone1").Value;
    location = "NAI-FUNZI";
    rcvdBy = rsCD.Fields.Item("U_RcvdBy").Value;

    #region Insert into FMS2 Cargo details table 
    // Check if entry already exists
    SAPbobsCOM.Recordset rsExists = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);

    rsExists.DoQuery("SELECT T0.\"Code\" FROM \"@FMS2\" T0 WHERE T0.\"Code\" = '" + hawb + "'");
    rsExists.MoveFirst();

    if (rsExists.RecordCount == 0)
    {
        SAPbobsCOM.Recordset rsFMS2 = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
        rsFMS2.DoQuery("INSERT INTO [dbo].[@FMS2] " +
                       "(Code, " +
                       "Name, " +
                       "U_SubFileNo, " +
                       "U_ContainerSz, " +
                       "U_AWB, " +
                       "U_ServiceMode, " +
                       "U_Weight, " +
                       "U_NoOfPackages, " +
                       "U_CardCode, " +
                       "U_CardName, " +
                       "U_Consignee, " +
                       "U_Amount, " +
                       "U_Contact, " +
                       "U_Location, " +
                       "U_QuotationNo," +
                       "U_RcvdBy) " +
                       "values ('" + hawb + "', " +
                       "'" + hawb + "'," +
                       "'" + subFileNo + "', " +
                       "'" + containerSize + "', " +
                       "'" + hawb + "', " +
                       "'" + serviceMode + "', " +
                       "'" + weight + "', " +
                       "'" + noOfPackages + "', " +
                       "'" + cardCode + "', " +
                       "'" + cardName + "', " +
                       "'" + consigneeName + "', " +
                       "'" + amount + "', " +           // -< Error thrown here
                       "'" + contactNo + "', " +
                       "'" + location + "', " +
                       "'" + docNum + "', " +
                       "'" + rcvdBy + "')");
        rsFMS2.MoveFirst();

        ErrorLog.LoggerExceptionInfo(new Exception("FMS2 Cargo details HAWB inserted: " + hawb + Environment.NewLine));
    }
    #endregion 
}
```

Comment: Since you're not parameterizing your query, or doing anything that I can see to escape problematic characters, I have to ask the following clarifying questions: 1. Are you using the exact same data between the two environments? 2. Have you confirmed none of your string values have `'`s in them? 3. When you removed the single quotes around `amount` did you perhaps accidentally remove the `,` as well?

Comment: Same data between the 2 environments. The numbers do not have a ' in them. I did not accidentally do that.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the numbers. I was asking about the string values of your other parameters. Removing the `'`s from around your `amount` variable should make it into a number inside that query. Try storing your concatenated string in a variable so that you can copy and paste the contents of it, **!! anonymized, but do not replace any special characters !!**, from your Locals window into the question. Let's see what query is actually being executed.

Comment: After looking into some information about SQL Server's implicit conversion of where clauses I'm surprised you're having this issue. Is the error message stating `Error converting data type varchar to numeric` that you have in your question complete?

Comment: This is the full error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xFFFFF830): 1). [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Is the amount rendered with scientific notation for big numbers? Decimals don't like that.
Small detail about the rsExist query. Is it not better to use something like SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ... for the query? It seems like it is keeping the query open and using resources which are no longer needed.

Comment: Why are you not parameterizing your query, that's the real question?

Comment: @Charlieface How would you build the insert statement?

Comment: I have no idea what `DoQuery` does, but it would be something like `INSERT YourTable (Column1, Column2...) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2...);` and pass through parameter values. Or even better, considering your existence check: `INSERT YourTable (Column1, Column2...) SELECT @Value1, @Value2... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE Column1 = @Value1);` then you don't need that whole separate check. Recordsets and datasets are so old school, you should use a mapper like Entity Framework or Dapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building SQL using string concatenation is just wrong. Use parameterized queries.

That being said, I am *guessing* from the comments that your application uses a culture that uses `,` as decimal separator:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
double amount = 563.39;
Console.WriteLine("SELECT CAST('" + 563.39 + "' AS NUMERIC(19, 6))");

// SELECT CAST('563,39' AS NUMERIC(19, 6))
// ----------------^
```

The above query will produce the "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" error. Various workarounds are possible but I would suggest:

```
Console.WriteLine("SELECT CAST('" + (563.39).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "' AS NUMERIC(19, 6))");
// SELECT CAST('563.39' AS NUMERIC(19, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

Shout out to Menno van Lavieren for the cause.

Since you're using string concatenation for building your query, your `amount` variable is getting `ToString()` called on it. The default behavior for `double` is to use scientific notation if you're over a certain decimal place count. Since your precision allows for 6, that's enough to trigger the scientific notation. This is where looking at the query string in the debugger would be helpful.

There are several ways to handle the formatting of `ToString()` for numbers, but I think the best way for you since this is going into a database and not to a display is to use `ToString("F6")`. That will round whatever value you have in that variable to the 6th decimal place. The reason you wouldn't necessarily use this for a display output is that it will also turn numbers like `1,234` into `1234.000000` (decimal character is culture dependent).

So simply change this line:

```
"'" + amount + "', " +           // -< Error thrown here
```

to:

```
"'" + amount.ToString("F6") + "', " +           // -< Error thrown here
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error. I have run this by hardcoding amount just to test.   "'" 
                                                   "'" + 563.39 + "', " +
                                                   "'" + contactNo + "', " + will not go through.  
                                                   "'" + 563 + "', " +
                                                   "'" + contactNo + "', " + will go through fine.